# Facebook Lookback Movie Second Chance?

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

I was able to successfully create and share the FB Lookback movie, but had to delete it when I saw a picture had been included that should not be shared (someone with their ex).

After deleting the picture I tried to go back to [Lookback](https://www.facebook.com/lookback) but it now only gives me a still collage of 6 pictures.  Does anyone know how to get a second chance at the movie?

Comment: Best info I've found so far is wait.  I haven't seen a Lookback movie for my profile yet and I just have the still Collage of pictures.

Comment: I went back to the edit page for my own video and I get the same options as before, with a big `Update` button at the top in place of `Share`. It seems to have the same functionality as `Share` did (posts a new video to your timeline).